# glGetIntegerv returning garbage value

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Glew\glew.h"
#include"freeGlut\freeglut.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GLint ExtensionCount;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &ExtensionCount);
    cout << ExtensionCount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

1. The output of this program is, `-858993460`. Why? It should return the number of extensions supported.
2. If I remove the `freeglut.h` header file, the program doesn't run and throws an error message,

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glGetIntegerv@8 referenced in function _main`

But, `glGetIntegerv` is inside `glew.h`. Why removing `freeglut.h` would cause an unresolved external error?

**EDIT** I have OpenGL 3.3 support. Using Radeon 4670 with catalyst 11.6.

Comment: You probably need to create OpenGL context first. You also need recent OpengGL version for `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS`.

Comment: Note that `glGetIntegerv` is __not__ returning garbage. `glGetIntegerv` returns _either_ a good value, or it _does not touch_ the pointed to address at all. The reason why you see garbage is because the variable is not initialized. This seems like a pedantic comment, but it is actually important to know that `glGetIntegerv` does not touch the variable if it fails.

Comment: @damono No, this is NOT pedantic comment. This is exactly what Ive been looking for. Thank you very much. :) I took the liberty to add your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@mario & @Banthar yes, thanks. I have to create a context first to use the any Opengl functionality.(yes, even for Opengl 1.1 which comes default with windows.)

*glGetIntegerv is not returning garbage. glGetIntegerv returns either a good value, or it does not touch the pointed to address at all. The reason why you see garbage is because the variable is not initialized. This seems like a pedantic comment, but it is actually important to know that glGetIntegerv does not touch the variable if it fails. Thanks @Damon*

This bare bone works fine.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitContextVersion(3,3);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

    glutCreateWindow("Test");

    GLint ExtensionCount;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &ExtensionCount);
    cout << ExtensionCount << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize OpenGL no matter what version you use. You can't just call random OpenGL functions without a valid OpenGL context; it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @nicol-bolas so, without initializing context, even OpenGL 1.1 functions wont work?

Comment: Yes. Without a context, there's no OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks, One more thing, Can you please explain the second issue I got in the question. When I commented out `freeglut.h`, `glGetIntegerv` caused an unresolved external. Why?

Comment: @iamcreasy: You are not linking to required OpenGL libraries. Your program works if you include `freeglut.h` header, because it adds them using `#pragma`s.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have opengl 3.0? AFAIK, GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS was added in OpenGL 3.0.

Comment: Yes, I have OpenGL 3.3 support. Using Radeon 4670 with catalyst 11.6. You should comment on my post for questioning.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your rendering context is using a OpenGL version prior to 3.0 (from what I've read `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS` was introduced in OpenGL 3.0; just because your card supports it doesn't mean you're actually using it). You could retrieve the string `GL_EXTENSIONS` and then split/count the elements yourself. But I don't think that's available everywhere either (2.0+?).

What are you trying to do (besides returning the number of extensions)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your library headers expect you to include `<GL/gl.h>`

Comment: when you use `glew.h` you dont need to include `gl.h`.

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows SDK (7.1) the included `GL/GL.h` defines the symbol `GL_VERSION_1_1`. I suspect that this is the version that is really relevant for the purposes of using `glGetIntegerv` with arguments such as `GL_MAJOR_VERSION`, `GL_MINOR_VERSION` or `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS`.

Actually, none of these is defined in `GL/GL.h`, while for instance `GL_VERSION` and `GL_EXTENSIONS` are. But when including `GL/glew.h` all these constants are available.

With respect to `GL_VERSION_1_1`, the three constants `GL_MAJOR_VERSION`, `GL_MINOR_VERSION` or `GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS` are not valid enumeration values, and actually if you call glGetError after trying to use one of them with `glGetIntegerv` you get an error `0x500` (`1280` in decimal) which is the `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.