# Why does glGetString(GL_VERSION) return null / zero instead of the OpenGL version?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew

I'm on Linux Mint 13 XFCE. My problem is that when I run in terminal the command:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

I get the following output:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.40
```

But when I run the `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` in my application then the result is null. Why doesn't this code get the `gl_version`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glewInit();

    printf("OpenGL version supported by this platform (%s): \n",
        glGetString(GL_VERSION));
}
```

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE and has very little to do with your problem btw. (Well, nothing really)

Comment: You don't need to include `gl.h` or `glu.h` if you include `glut.h`

Comment: Same root cause as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594214/glgetintegerv-returning-garbage-value

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`glutInit()` doesn't create a [GL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) *or* make one current.  You need a current GL context for `glewInit()` and `glGetString()` to work.

Try this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutCreateWindow("GLUT");

    glewInit();
    printf("OpenGL version supported by this platform (%s): \n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `glfw` in order to create GL context and then query the version:

Include this files:

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
```

And then you can do:

```
    // Initialise GLFW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return "";
    }

    // We are rendering off-screen, but a window is still needed for the context
    // creation. There are hints that this is no longer needed in GL 3.3, but that
    // windows still wants it. So just in case.
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); //dont show the window

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "Dummy window", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        return "";
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return "";
    }

    std::string versionString = std::string((const char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

Comment: GL and GLFW includes should be included with <>, not "".