# OpenGL Version is not getting printed

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to know if my OpenGL version can handle shaders. But when I try to print the version of OpenGL, it doedn't print anything.

```
cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a valid OpenGL context active?

Comment: You need to have a valid OpenGL context at the time of calling glGetString(); See also: http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/149571-glGetString(GL_VERSION)-return-Null-argh-!

Comment: I don't know about OpenGL context. I'm using Arch Linux. Can you give me any resource to know what that is?

Comment: I would advice you to read about OpenGL, before you start trying to make a program using OpenGL.

Comment: Okay found it. The output is `2.1 Mesa 9.2.1` . Does this version support GLSL proogramming?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184506/why-does-glgetstringgl-version-return-null-zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start from here: http://open.gl/context (learn about context creation, getting a basic, modern OGL program running)

Use a debugger.