# OpenGL and GL3W support issues

Tags: c++, opengl

There is something strange happening with gl3w's isSupported function. When I call `isSupported(4, 0)` it returns false, meaning OpenGL 4.0 isn't supported. However, when I call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` it says OpenGL version 4.0. 
Does this mean I can use OpenGL 4.0 functions?

I'm using gl3w in C++ and Visual Studio 2017

```
#include <GL/gl3w.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){



    if(!glfwInit()) {
        FATAL_ERROR("Failed to initialise GLFW");
    }

    glfwSetErrorCallback(glfwErrorCallback);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    //If i put glfwMakeContextCurrent here gl3wInit fails
    //glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        FATAL_ERROR("Window creation failed");
    }

    if(!gl3wInit()) {} // handle that

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    bool support = gl3wIsSupported(4, 0);  // returns false

    const char* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION); // return "4.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by switching over to glad instead

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    FATAL_ERROR("Failed to initialise GLFW");
}

glfwSetErrorCallback(glfwErrorCallback);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);


if (!window) {
    glfwTerminate();
    FATAL_ERROR("Window creation failed");
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    FATAL_ERROR("Failed to initialise OpenGL context");
}


PRINT("OpenGL Version: " << GLVersion.major << "." << GLVersion.minor);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to [make a GL context current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184506/why-does-glgetstringgl-version-return-null-zero-instead-of-the-opengl-versio) before you call `gl3wInit()` or regular OpenGL functions otherwise they won't do anything useful.

Comment: I put glfwMakeContextCurrent before gl3wInit like you said and, but now it gl3w is failing to initialise

Comment: I stumbled on that error too, `gl3wInit` returns true *on error*, not on *success*!

Answer (score 3):

In the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#GL3W) you can read:

> The GL3W library focuses on the core profile of OpenGL 3 and 4. It
>   only loads the core entrypoints for these OpenGL versions. It supports
>   Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, and FreeBSD.
>
> **Note**: GL3W loads core OpenGL
>   only by default. All OpenGL extensions will be loaded if the --ext
>   flag is specified to gl3w_gen.py.

And this is confirmed looking inside the [code](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w/blob/master/gl3w_gen.py):

```
int gl3wIsSupported(int major, int minor)
{
    if (major < 3) // <<<<=========== SEE THIS
        return 0;
    if (version.major == major)
        return version.minor >= minor;
    return version.major >= major;
}
```

You are asking with `glfwWindowHint` for an old 2.0 version. Thus, `gl3wIsSupported` will return `false` and `gl3wInit` will return `GL3W_ERROR_OPENGL_VERSION`.

---

For `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returning "4.0" means that, yes, you can use that 4.0 version. Ask for it with `glfwWindowHint`.